# angular 4.4: can't sort by some columns of a table

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material, tablesorter

I want to sort a table by its content, I have several columns, the sorting code works on some of them, but in the rest, the sorting code do not work.

I get the data from an API rest. The data is obtained correctly, and displayed in the table correctly.

First I have `Students` object, and I have `Points` object.

`Students` are like:

```
[{
  "id": 10000,
  "name": "Somebody",
  "points": {"1": 5, "2":0, "3": 10}
},{
  "id": 10001,
  "name": "JustAnother",
  "points": {"1":0, "2": 1, "3": 4}
}]
```

And `Points` object is like:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "foo",
  "value": 2
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "bar",
  "value": 5
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "baz",
  "value": 1
}]
```

Then I display them on the table like this:

```
<mat-card *ngIf="sortedData">
  <table matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
    <tr>
      <th mat-sort-header="id">Id</th>
      <th mat-sort-header="name">name</th>
      <th mat-sort-header="{{point.id}}" *ngFor="let point of Points">{{point.name}}</th>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngFor="let student of sortedData">
      <td>{{student.id}}</td>
      <td>{{student.name}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let point of Points" class="center">
        {{student.points[point.id]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</mat-card>
```

the table is like:

```
id    | name    | foo    | baz    | bar
------------------------------------------
10000 | Somebody| 5      | 0      | 10
10001 | JustAnot| 0      | 1      | 4
```

And the sorting code in the table component is:

```
public sortedData: Student[];
this.sortedData = this.Students;  // <- this is inside the response of get students function.

sortData(sort: Sort) {
  const data = this.Students;
  if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
    this.sortedData = data;
    return;
  }

  this.sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
    const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';
    const points_array = this.Points; // <- this.points contains the Points object
    if (sort.active === 'id') {
      return compare(a.id, b.name, isAsc);
    }
    if (sort.active === 'name') {
      return compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
    }
    Object.keys(points_array).forEach(
      function (index) {
        if (parseInt(points_array[index].id, 10) === parseInt(sort.active, 10)) {
          return compare(
            a['points'][ points_array[index].id ],
            b['points'][ points_array[index].id ],
            isAsc
          );
        }
      }
    );
  });
}

function compare(a: number | string, b: number | string, isAsc: boolean) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

I have more properties and columns, it's simplified for the example. All the columns like id or name can be sorted without any problem.

But the point columns can't be sorted. When I click on one of that columns i makes like sorting, but the order remains unchanged.

If I log to the sorting functions, I see that the comparison is made, and the response of the `compare` function is `0` or `-1`, the same as the columns that are sorted correctly.

There is no javascript error on console, apparently it works, but when I try to sort the data by some of the columns point, the order remains the initial.

Why is not sorting by the point columns?

**Edit:** a working stackblitz replicating the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cruuo3

**Edit 2:** I added to the stackblitz some more students and another column with 'level' to sort. 'Level' is working fine, as 'id' and 'name'.

Comment: What exactly are you planning on sorting them on? It's really hard to understand without a concrete example. Would you mind creating a sample stackblitz replicating this issue?

Comment: Well, I understand sort the data displayed on the table by one column on ascending or descending order. For example, if I click on name, I get the content data table sorted by name. In any case, I have done a stackbitz to replicate the issue. I edit the question and add to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it is work:

```
return compare(a['points'][ points_array[parseInt(sort.active, 10)].id ], 
b['points'][ points_array[parseInt(sort.active, 10)].id ], isAsc);
```

the problem is in **forEach**  callback function return value but foreach parnt  return a void value .

for example **for** do work ,because in not use call back function

```
for (const index of Object.keys(points_array)) { 
  if (parseInt(points_array[index].id, 10) === parseInt(sort.active, 10)) { 
    return compare( 
      a['points'][points_array[index].id], 
      b['points'][points_array[index].id], 
      isAsc 
    ); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: `for` was my first try, but with `for` I get the following error: `Type 'Point' is not an array type or a string type.`

And I think we are near a solution, but just now your code returns an error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: If I do `console.log(Array.isArray(points_array));` the result on console is `true`

Comment: thanks to your solution I changed my code to: `for (const index of Object.keys(points_array)) {
        if (parseInt(points_array[index].id, 10) === parseInt(sort.active, 10)) {
          return compare(
            a['points'][points_array[index].id],
            b['points'][points_array[index].id],
            isAsc
          );
        }
      }` and now it's working. You pointed me on the good direction. Thanks. Edit your response to my working code and I'll accept it. Maybe it helps somebody in the future.